# How to compare the performence between different models?

Tags: model-selection, generalized-linear-model, model-comparison, model

Given a data, I'd like to utilize it by two different models, such as generalized linear model (GLM) and generalized partial linear model (GPLM), and my problem is how to compare the performance of these models?
Please give me some ideas!

Comment: [AIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion), [BIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion), [DIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deviance_information_), [Bayes factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_factor), [Cross-validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29), [Likelihood-ratio test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test) ... All of them assessing different features of the model.

Comment: What do you mean by "performance"? The answer will help determine which (if any) of the tools listed by @Procrastinator will be helpful.

Comment: @guest Alright, "performance" means that whether or not one model fits the data well. And I plan to use GLM and GPLM to fit the data, so what I want to know is which one performs better?

Comment: @shijingSI, that's no more specific than your original question. "Fitting well" can mean it predicts better, has substantially higher log-likelihood, or...?

Comment: @Procrastinator Thank you very much! Your advice is really helpful. But i don't know how to use AIC or BIC for the semi-parametric model. Since you know we need to estimate an unknown function in this case, so how to count the number of unknown parameters? For instance, for the GPLM with structure: $$E(Y|U,T)=G(U^{T}\beta+m(T))$$, in which $\beta$ is a p-dimensional parameter and $m(\cdot)$ is a unknown function. Both of these components need to be estimated. So , what's the number of estimated parameter ?

Comment: @Macro Yeah, definitely, you're right! As you probably not know, I am a Chinese, so sometimes my English is not good enogh for me to express my ideas accurately. In fact, I need to learn english. Hope you guys give me some suggestions!

Comment: @shijingSI How are you estimating the function $m$?

Comment: @Procrastinator Actually I will adopt the local constant technique to estimate $m$. Based on the profile likelihood method, first we fix $\beta$ and get an estimate of $m$,which is a function about $\beta$, then construct the profile likelihood for $\beta$, maximizing the profile likelihood can result in a estimate for $\beta$.Finally, substitute the unkown $\beta$ in $m$ with its estimate we get $\hat{m}$. Do I make myself clear?

Comment: @shijingSI Then this [paper](http://www3.stat.sinica.edu.tw/statistica/oldpdf/A19n223.pdf) might be of interest.